# ONIX metadata editor for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, editor, metadata, xml

There is widely used metadata system in book industry called [ONIX for Books](http://www.editeur.org/83/Overview/). Basically, ONIX metadata is just XML file.

There are some commercial solutions for Windows and Mac OS X like [ONIX EDIT](http://onixedit.com/en/Home.aspx) or [ONIX SUITE](http://www.onixsuite.com/) that have GUI for editing such metadata.

Is there any Ubuntu software that allows to edit ONIX metadata either by GUI or command line?

Answer (score -1):

[ONIXEDIT](http://onixedit.com/) now offers a new service called [ONIXEDIT Cloud](http://onixedit.com/en-us/Products/ONIXEDIT-Cloud/Overview). With this web application, you can manage your ONIX metadata with any browser and from any platform. You can also give it a try with a free 10 days trial.